# Check if element exists, then apply css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My HTML code is basically

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="c">
  ...
</div>
```

I now want to apply `display: none;` to c, but only if b exists. a and c always exist.

My approach was

```
.a .b ~ .c {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: This can now be achieved purely in CSS (with the exception that Firefox still needs to integrate the `:has` selector in April 2023):

```css
 .a:has(.b) ~ .c {
     display: none;
 }
```

**Old Answer**

This should work for you:

```js
var b = document.querySelector('.b');

if (b) {
  document.querySelector('.c').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="a">a
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>

<div class="c">c</div>
```

Obviously, JavaScript is required but just a touch. You could add the `document.querySelector('.b)` to the `if` statement instead of saving it to a variable as well.

**Edit**: Just a bit of clarity on what's wrong with your code - you're first selecting `.a .b` which will select the `b` class if it's a descendant of the `a` class, then you're using the general sibling combinator (subsequent-sibling combinator), but it won't select the `c` class. This is because the `c` class is outside of the `a` element and is therefore not a descendant of your `a` class. A pure CSS solution would be having your `c` class inside of your `a` element, which would make your current CSS work and the JavaScript wouldn't be needed. For example, your HTML would look like this:

```css
.a .b ~ .c {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">a
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

On a sidenote, the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `~` operator will look for any subsequent element that comes after `b` with a class of `c`. If you only wanted to apply it to the first element with a class of `c` that comes after `b`, consider using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `+`, otherwise known as the 'next-sibling combinator' instead.

Comment: Well, I hoped that this would be possible without JS, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Read the second half of my answer again, it is :)

Comment: Sadly, I can't edit the HTML in this project. :(

Comment: Ah, bummer. Looks like JavaScript's your only option then, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved now (2023) using :has() pseudo-class selector, which matches elements that have a particular descendant and if it is, then we can use the general sibling selector to select ".c".

```css
 .a:has(.b)~.c {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
            <p>Content inside b</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        <p>Content inside c</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS `:empty` can identify the **div** has content or not

```css
.c:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    lorem
  </div>
</div>
<div class="c"></div>
```